# Getting jQuery Mobile working on BlackBerry Playbook

Tags: jquery-mobile, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-webworks

Has anybody got jQuery Mobile working on BlackBerry Playbook simulator?
I tried everything described [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-Development/jQuery-Mobile-Framework-support-on-PlayBook/m-p/747623), but am getting network error just shown [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-Development/Playbook-Webworks-Javascript-amp-Jquery-problems/m-p/776821).

Any experiences with jQuery Mobile on bbpb simulator?

Comment: Are you using a browser that is supported? there is a support table on http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

Comment: Not browser.but using web works sdk.

Comment: Since your link to the BlackBerry support forums has an accepted answer, is this still an open question?

Answer (score 0):

This guy did it.

https://github.com/TheMarco/Unit-Converter/blob/master/index.html